# RxSwift crash "Maybe delegate was already set in xib or storyboard and now it’s being overwritten in code.”

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am binding the tableview with two diffrent datasources such as one with actual result and another array with after clicking scope button filter.

```
func bind() {
    self.searchBar.rx.searchButtonClicked
      .throttle(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
      .flatMapLatest { [weak self] _ -> Observable<[String]> in
        guard let `self` = self else { return .just([]) }
        guard let query = self.searchBar.text else { return .just([]) }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.loadingText.isHidden = false
        let items = self.githubService.search(query: query)
        self.githubService.searchItems = items
        return items
      }
      .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell")) { row, name, cell in
        self.loadingText.isHidden = true
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
      }
      .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
  }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        //filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])

        let filteredResult = self.githubService.filteredSearch(index: selectedScope)
            filteredResult
            .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell")) { row, name, cell in // Getting crash here
                self.loadingText.isHidden = true
                cell.textLabel?.text = name
            }
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
```

This is the method which i use for filter.

```
func filteredSearch(index:Int) -> Observable<[String]> {
        guard index > 0  else { return .just([]) }
        return searchItems!.filter { $0.contains("a")}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty explicit, you cannot have 2 different datasources. Instead you can change the content of your datSource between 2 sets of Data.

I advise you to use `RxDataSources`